# Clean format smarty html coda 2?

Tags: smarty, coda

I use Coda 2 , do you know a way to format clean smarty code ? Something to reorder all tag ? Or maybe on other good editor on Mac ?

From that :

```
{if $order.state_name == "Pending"}
    {$order.state_name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}
  {elseif $order.state_name == "Cancel"}
    {$order.state_name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}
  {else}
    {if $demandes}
        {if $demandes != $benefits} 
            {l s='Payé' mod='jmarketplace'}
        {else}
            {l s='Payé' mod='jmarketplace'}
        {/if}
    {else}
        {$order.state_name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}
    {/if}
  {/if}
```

to that :

```
{if $order.state_name == "Pending"}
    {$order.state_name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}
{elseif $order.state_name == "Cancel"}
    {$order.state_name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}
{else}

    {if $demandes}
        {if $demandes != $benefits} 
            {l s='Payé' mod='jmarketplace'}
        {else}
            {l s='Payé' mod='jmarketplace'}
        {/if}
    {else}
        {$order.state_name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}
    {/if}
 {/if}
```